# Highcharts memory leak when using jQuery 2.X

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, memory-leaks, highcharts

After a lot of testing with my AngularJS app, I have noticed a memory leak when using `Highcharts` combined with the last version of `jQuery` (2.1.4). Here I can show 2 plunkers.

With jQuery 1.8.2 : http://plnkr.co/edit/lQ6n5Eo2wHqt35OVPh8S?p=preview

Snapshots taken:

[image]

With jQuery 2.1.4 : http://plnkr.co/edit/IC0pSaxFZHQzOzoJUD0e?p=preview

Snapshots taken:

[image]

I am using the same code for both examples and the snapshots were taken exactly at the same time for both. My question is:

Has something changed with the new jQuery and the way charts are being destroyed is not the right one? Or it is just a Highcharts/jQuery bug?

BTW, when using jQuery 1.8.2 memory still grows, though growing a lot slower. I have also tried without JQuery, using the standalone framework of Highcharts, and it also increases a bit slowly. Here is a plunker with it: http://plnkr.co/edit/EvXCBUgggx4H2YgGLvov?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reporting, I had that this information in our bugtracker [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4757).

Comment: OK so I will keep abreast of any news. Thank you!